# Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null at validation at HTMLInputElement.onkeydown

Tags: javascript, html, web-deployment

I was making simple contact form with email validation, but I ran into an error in my JS code. I was trying to figure out how to fix it but I have no idea what to do.
I was also trying different solutions from other People on StackOverflow but nothing work.

This Is My HTML code :

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/style.css">
    <title>blackbubble | Contact</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="#" id="form">
        <div class="form_body">
            <div class="form_title">
                <span></span>
                <h1>Get In Touch</h1>
                <span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="user_name">
                <input type="name" placeholder="Your name"></input>
                <input type="name" placeholder="Second name">
            </div>
            <div class="email">
                <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Your email address" onkeydown="validation()">
                <p class="text"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="textarea_box">
                <textarea placeholder="Message"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form_footer">
                <button class="btn btn_submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    <script src="../assets/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

here is my JS Code:

```
function validation() {
    var form = document.getElementById("form");
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var text = document.getElementById("text");

    var text = document.getElementById("text");
    var pattern = /^[^ ]+@[^ ]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$/;

    if (email.match(pattern)) {
        form.classList.add("valid");
        form.classList.remove("invalid");
        text.innerHTML = "Your Email Address Is Valid.";
        text.style.color = "#00ff00";
    }
    else {
        form.classList.remove("valid");
        form.classList.add("invalid");
        text.innerHTML = "Please Enter A Valid Email Address.";
        text.style.color = "#ff0000";
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't have `id="text"` in the HTML. You have `class="text"`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no element with the id `text`.

You probably meant to select the element with the class `text` instead. This can be done with [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and the `.text` CSS selector.

```js
function validation() {
  var form = document.getElementById("form");
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var text = document.querySelector(".text");

  var pattern = /^[^ ]+@[^ ]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$/;

  if (email.match(pattern)) {
    form.classList.add("valid");
    form.classList.remove("invalid");
    text.innerHTML = "Your Email Address Is Valid.";
    text.style.color = "#00ff00";
  } else {
    form.classList.remove("valid");
    form.classList.add("invalid");
    text.innerHTML = "Please Enter A Valid Email Address.";
    text.style.color = "#ff0000";
  }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/style.css">
  <title>blackbubble | Contact</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="#" id="form">
    <div class="form_body">
      <div class="form_title">
        <span></span>
        <h1>Get In Touch</h1>
        <span></span>
      </div>
      <div class="user_name">
        <input type="name" placeholder="Your name">
        <input type="name" placeholder="Second name">
      </div>
      <div class="email">
        <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Your email address" onkeydown="validation()">
        <p class="text"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="textarea_box">
        <textarea placeholder="Message"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="form_footer">
        <button class="btn btn_submit">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```